# Condition for application:shouldRestoreApplicationState: function to be invoked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

I am a bit new to IOS app development. I am using cordova 2.1.0. I have a kind of basic question. When should `application:shouldSaveApplicationState:` function be called for saving Application state? And similarly, when should `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` be called for restoring state/data?

Answer (score 2):

You don't call the [`application:shouldSaveApplicationState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW34) methods the system does.
When your app is about to be closed the system will call these method, so you can save the state of you application.

Then when your apps gest started again the system will call the [`application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW37) to restore you apps state.

There is on exception, if the user kills your app then the state is delete as well.

Comment: App state means active,inactive,foreground,etc. right? How can i save the state..If u give some example.

Comment: No, `shouldSaveApplicationState:` will supply your app with an `NSCoder` in which you can store your apps state, like which viewController is being displayed or which viewController are in the navigation stack.

Comment: Any example with code snippet would serve better as i am new to IOS. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I really can't give any since that is build per app, and since your are using cordova which is something I don't use.