# IOS: How to restore application state

Tags: ios, state, restore

I am trying to implement save and restore application state.  I gather that 
the method in the app delegate `shouldSaveApplicationState:` saves the state and providing you set restoration ids for view controllers, 
`application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` should take you back to the view controller you were in, when the app returns to active.

However, if I willfully close the app using the home button--for example, to make a phone call or check something on safari--when I go back to the app, for a split second it shows where I had been but then restarts from the initial view controller.

This is jarring to the user and definitely sub-optimal as user needs to go to all the trouble of going back to where he/she was.

When I set `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` to log out when fired, it appears that it is not fired in this case--apparently by design as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797911/condition-for-applicationshouldrestoreapplicationstate-function-to-be-invoked) states.

Is there a way to force this method to be called in order to retrieve my state?  Alternatively, how can you go back to where you were in the app in the case in the case where you actively leave the app rather than have it be interrupted, say, by an incoming phone call?

Thank-you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an error on my part. The reason the method `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` was not firing upon a resume after pressing the home button is that a method in the `appDelegate` file called `applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` fires earlier in the lifecycle and was redirecting the app to the startup page.  I fixed this by moving the troublesome redirect in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` to `applicationDidFInishLaunching` which comes after the restore method in the lifecycle.  This allowed the `shouldRestoreApplicationState` to fire.

Of note, pressing the home Button is not a force quit, the one exception to the restore method firing.